# App crashes after capturing image

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

After capture camera image when i save then not return in `activity` and crash app but everything is ok in my Samsung mobile but giving this error in redmi phone and others mobile

```
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
         at com.logiclump.technologies.gigmedico.Home.onActivityResult(Home.java:101)
         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6562)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3768)
```

## This is my first activity

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK)

    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Log.e("Image : ", uri.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("imgUrl", uri.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**This is second activity where i am getting intent**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    Log.e("ashish", bundle.getString("imgUrl") + "");
    path = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imgUrl"));
}

ImageView selfiiii = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mySelfie);
selfiiii.setImageURI(path);
```

Comment: From error log, it can be seen that the error is at line 101 of Home.java. hence please post Home.java file too

Comment: sir i just edited my question and post also home code..so see and please help

Comment: Most probably `data.getData()` is `null`

Comment: Did you check id `data.getData()` is `null`?

Comment: how to check please tell

Comment: It is clearly shown in exception that uri is null. check it  `if(uri!=null) //do action`

Comment: please tell me properly how to resolve this error ,i given u code so edit and give properly solution please

Comment: you uri variable are null . add a null check.

Comment: i just ask to resolve my problem but u guyz giving me suggestion,please give me proper solution

Comment: ashwani dear i checked and my uri is null  so please tell how to get image in uri bcz i m returing  without image

Comment: @Ashwanikumar please tell

Comment: can you please share code in both activity. and it is possible to share a GitHub link of you code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Camera Intent:**

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);

            mTempCameraPhotoFile = photoFile;
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PHOTO_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

**Save Image File In Storage:**

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

**In onActivityResult:**

```
if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {

            String filePath = mTempCameraPhotoFile.getPath();

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mTempCameraPhotoFile);

            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is mTempCameraPhotoFile and what is  mCurrentPhotoPath @yatin

Comment: It is Image file path stored in external storage String   mCurrentPhotoPath, you can convert in into uri like Uri uri = Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath);

Comment: u know what u  guyz giving complecated coding